# ERROR TypeError: value.getTime is not a function at dateBefore - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Good afternoon everybody.

I want to create a filter on the date table, but when I do that I get an error.

Here's the error:

[image]

Follow my HTML:

```
<th style="min-width: 10rem">
    <div class="flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
         Data vencimento
         <p-columnFilter type="date" field="datavencimento" display="menu"></p-columnFilter>
    </div>
</th>
```

Here is my component:

```
loadData() {
    this.CartaoParcelaService.listaCartaoParcela().subscribe((response) => {
        this.CartaoParcelas = response
        this.loading = false
    });
}

configurarFormulario(CartaoParcela: CartaoParcela = { ativo: true }) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        id: [CartaoParcela.id, []],
        numeroonder: [{ value: CartaoParcela.numeroonder, disabled: true }],
        cartao: [{ value: CartaoParcela.cartao, disabled: true }],
        parcela: [{ value: CartaoParcela.parcela, disabled: true }],
        datacompra: [{ value: CartaoParcela.datacompra, disabled: true }],
        datapagamento: [CartaoParcela.datapagamento, []],
        datavencimento: [CartaoParcela.datavencimento],
        valorpagamento: [CartaoParcela.valorpagamento, []],
        ativo: [{ value: CartaoParcela.ativo, disabled: true }],
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help me

Comment: Please post code. This is not sufficient to answer the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I added more information

Comment: What's the value of `CartaoParcela.datavencimento` ?

Comment: Date, dd/mm/yyyy = 14/02/2023

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by converting the date value to string:

```
this.CartaoParcelas.forEach(p => p.datavencimento = new Date(`${p.datavencimento}`))
```